# Can Reporting Services be used to format XML returned in an XML data type column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Using SQL Server 2005 and Reporting Services, I have a stored proc that returns several columns, one of which is of the XML data type. Can I manipulate/format/style that XML column in my Reporting Services report? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Use the classes in `System.Xml` to parse the XML the way you want.

On the References tab of the SSRS Report Properties dialog, add a reference to `System.Xml`.  Then add your parsing code to the Code tab.

There is an example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/91a1472b-e1cf-4438-9468-3e3fac0d4896).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this but SRSS allows you to enter code in your report via scripting.  You may be able to do something with the XML inside there, possibly with XSL